# Closing unused pipe file descriptors

Tags: c, pipe, signals, fork

I try to comprehend the basic reason for why closing file descriptors is needed. I get the reason for reader side closing write descriptor. However, conversely, I can't see(simulate) in action the reason for writing side closing read descriptor. I try to apply following one,

> When a process tries to write to a pipe for which no process has an
>   open read descriptor, the kernel sends the `SIGPIPE` signal to the
>   writing process. By default, this signal kills a process.
>
> Source, The Linux programming interface, Michael Kerrisk
>
> `write()`, on error, `-1` is returned, and errno is set appropriately.
>   `EPIPE` fd is connected to a pipe or socket whose reading end is
>   closed. When this happens the writing process will also receive a
>   `SIGPIPE` signal. (Thus, the write return value is seen only if the
>   program catches, blocks or ignores this signal.)
>
> Source, man pages.

To do that, I close already read descriptor before `fork()`. Nevertheless, neither I can catch `SIGPIPE`, nor print error of `write()` by `perror()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <signal.h>
#define BUFSIZE 100

char const * errMsgPipe = "signal handled SIGPIPE\n";
int errMsgPipeLen;

void handler(int x) {
    write(2, errMsgPipe, errMsgPipeLen);
}

int main(void) {
    errMsgPipeLen = strlen(errMsgPipe);
    char bufin[BUFSIZE] = "empty";
    char bufout[] = "hello soner";
    int bytesin;
    pid_t childpid;
    int fd[2];

    struct sigaction sa;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigfillset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_handler = handler;
    sigaction(SIGPIPE, &sa, 0);

    if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
        perror("Failed to create the pipe");
        return 1;
    }
    bytesin = strlen(bufin);
    childpid = fork();
    if (childpid == -1) {
        perror("Failed to fork");
        return 1;
    }

    close(fd[0]);

    if (childpid) {
        if (write(fd[1], bufout, strlen(bufout)+1) < 0) {
            perror("write");
        }
    }
    else
        bytesin = read(fd[0], bufin, BUFSIZE);
    fprintf(stderr, "[%ld]:my bufin is {%.*s}, my bufout is {%s}\n",
            (long)getpid(), bytesin, bufin, bufout);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[22686]:my bufin is {empty}, my bufout is {hello soner}
[22687]:my bufin is {empty}, my bufout is {hello soner}
```

Expected output:

```
[22686]:my bufin is {empty}, my bufout is {hello soner}
signal handled SIGPIPE or similar stuff
```

Comment: Are you trying to catch an expected signal due to writing to a pipe which has no readers?

Comment: Note that on Linux (and other modern systems), the capacity of a pipe is usually 64 KiB, so you have to write quite a lot of data before you see some problems.  That said, you've not shown the output you get, nor the output you expect, from your program.  Please (re-re-)read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) and note that both expected and actual outputs are part of the game.

Comment: You might also note that your else clause is mis-indented.  It looks as though you expect it to be associated with the outer `if (childpid)` but it is actually associated with `if (write(…) < 0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Independent demonstration of why closing read end of a pipe matters

Here is a scenario where closing the read end of a pipe matters:

```
seq 65536 | sed 10q
```

If the process that launches `seq` does not close the read end of the pipe, then `seq` will fill the pipe buffer (it would like to write 382,110 bytes, but the pipe buffer isn't that big) but because there is a process with the read end of the pipe open (`seq`), it will not get SIGPIPE or a write error, so it will never complete.

Consider this code.  The program runs `seq 65536 | sed 10q`, but depending on whether it is invoked with any arguments or not, it does or does not close the read end of the pipe to the `seq` program.  When it is run without arguments, the `seq` program never gets SIGPIPE or a write error on its standard output because there is a process with the read end of the pipe open — that process is `seq` itself.

```
#include "stderr.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    int fd[2];
    int pid1;
    int pid2;

    if (pipe(fd) != 0)
        err_syserr("failed to pipe: ");
    if ((pid1 = fork()) < 0)
        err_syserr("failed to fork 1: ");
    else if (pid1 == 0)
    {
        char *sed[] = { "sed", "10q", 0 };
        if (dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO) < 0)
            err_syserr("failed to dup2 read end of pipe to standard input: ");
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execvp(sed[0], sed);
        err_syserr("failed to exec %s: ", sed[0]);
    }
    else if ((pid2 = fork()) < 0)
        err_syserr("failed to fork 2: ");
    else if (pid2 == 0)
    {
        char *seq[] = { "seq", "65536", 0 };
        if (dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO) < 0)
            err_syserr("failed to dup2 write end of pipe to standard output: ");
        close(fd[1]);
        if (argc > 1)
            close(fd[0]);
        execvp(seq[0], seq);
        err_syserr("failed to exec %s: ", seq[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        int corpse;
        int status;
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        printf("read end of pipe is%s closed for seq\n", (argc > 1) ? "" : " not");
        printf("shell process is PID %d\n", (int)getpid());
        printf("sed launched as PID %d\n", pid1);
        printf("seq launched as PID %d\n", pid2);
        while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
            printf("%d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
        printf("shell process is exiting\n");
    }
}
```

The library code is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.

Here's a pair of sample runs (the program was called `fork29`):

```
$ fork29
read end of pipe is not closed for seq
shell process is PID 90937
sed launched as PID 90938
seq launched as PID 90939
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
90938 exited with status 0x0000
^C
$ fork29 close
read end of pipe is closed for seq
shell process is PID 90940
sed launched as PID 90941
seq launched as PID 90942
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
90941 exited with status 0x0000
90942 exited with status 0x000D
shell process is exiting
$
```

Note that the exit status of `seq` in the second example indicates that it died from signal 13, SIGPIPE.

#### Question about the solution above

> (1) How are we sure that here `seq` executes before `sed`? How is there no race?

The two programs (`seq` and `sed`) execute concurrently.  `sed` cannot read anything until `seq` has produced it.  `seq` might fill the pipe before `sed` reads anything, or it might only fill it after `sed` has quit.

> (2) Why do we close both `fd[0]` and `fd[1]` in `sed`? Why not only `fd[1]`? Similar for `seq`.

**Rule of thumb**: If you
[`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)
one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the
original file descriptors returned by
[`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html)
as soon as possible.
In particular, you should close them before using any of the
[`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html)
family of functions.

The rule also applies if you duplicate the descriptors with either
[`dup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html)
or
[`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html)
with `F_DUPFD`

The code for `sed` follows the Rule of Thumb.  The code for `seq` only does so conditionally, so you can see what happens when you don't follow the Rule of Thumb.

#### Independent demonstration of why closing write end of a pipe matters

Here is a scenario where closing the write end of a pipe matters:

```
ls -l | sort
```

If the process that launches `sort` does not close the write end of the pipe, then `sort` could write to the pipe, so it will never see EOF on the pipe, so it will never complete.

Consider this code.  The program runs `ls -l | sort`, but depending on whether it is invoked with any arguments or not, it does or does not close the write end of the pipe to the `sort` program.  When it is run without arguments, then, the `sort` program never sees EOF on its standard input because there is a process with the write end of the pipe open — that process is `sort` itself.

```
#include "stderr.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    int fd[2];
    int pid1;
    int pid2;

    if (pipe(fd) != 0)
        err_syserr("failed to pipe: ");
    if ((pid1 = fork()) < 0)
        err_syserr("failed to fork 1: ");
    else if (pid1 == 0)
    {
        char *sort[] = { "sort", 0 };
        if (dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO) < 0)
            err_syserr("failed to dup2 read end of pipe to standard input: ");
        close(fd[0]);
        if (argc > 1)
            close(fd[1]);
        execvp(sort[0], sort);
        err_syserr("failed to exec %s: ", sort[0]);
    }
    else if ((pid2 = fork()) < 0)
        err_syserr("failed to fork 2: ");
    else if (pid2 == 0)
    {
        char *ls[] = { "ls", "-l", 0 };
        if (dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO) < 0)
            err_syserr("failed to dup2 write end of pipe to standard output: ");
        close(fd[1]);
        close(fd[0]);
        execvp(ls[0], ls);
        err_syserr("failed to exec %s: ", ls[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        int corpse;
        int status;
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        printf("write end of pipe is%s closed for sort\n", (argc > 1) ? "" : " not");
        printf("shell process is PID %d\n", (int)getpid());
        printf("sort launched as PID %d\n", pid1);
        printf("ls   launched as PID %d\n", pid2);
        while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
            printf("%d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
        printf("shell process is exiting\n");
    }
}
```

Here's a pair of sample runs (the program was called `fork13`):

```
$ fork13
write end of pipe is not closed for sort
shell process is PID 90737
sort launched as PID 90738
ls   launched as PID 90739
90739 exited with status 0x0000
^C
$ fork13 close
write end of pipe is closed for sort
shell process is PID 90741
sort launched as PID 90742
ls   launched as PID 90743
90743 exited with status 0x0000
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff   1583 Jun 23 14:20 fork13.c
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jleffler  staff  22216 Jun 23 14:20 fork13
drwxr-xr-x  3 jleffler  staff     96 Jun 23 14:06 fork13.dSYM
total 56
90742 exited with status 0x0000
shell process is exiting
$
```

> (3) Why do we need to close both `fd[0]` and `fd[1]` in their parent?

The parent process isn't actively using the pipe it created.  It must close it fully, otherwise the other programs won't end.  Try it — I did (unintentionally) and the programs didn't behave as I intended (expected).  It took me a couple of seconds to realize what I'd not done!

#### Adaptation of code from answer by OP

[snr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4990642/snr) posted an ['answer'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51012326/15168) attempting to demonstrate signal handling and what happens with closing (or not) the read end of pipe file descriptors.  Here's an adaptation of that code into a program that can be controlled with command line options, where permutations of the options can yield different and useful results.  The `-b` and `-a` options allow you to close the read end of the pipe before or after the fork (or not close it at all).  The `-h` and `-i` allow you to handle SIGPIPE with the signal handler or ignore it (or use the default handling — terminate).  And the `-d` option allows you to delay the parent by 1 second before it attempts to write.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "stderr.h"

#define BUFSIZE 100

static char const *errMsgPipe = "signal handled SIGPIPE\n";
static int errMsgPipeLen;

static void handler(int x)
{
    if (x == SIGPIPE)
        write(2, errMsgPipe, errMsgPipeLen);
}

static inline void print_bool(const char *tag, bool value)
{
    printf("  %5s: %s\n", (value) ? "true" : "false", tag);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);

    bool sig_ignore = false;
    bool sig_handle = false;
    bool after_fork = false;
    bool before_fork = false;
    bool parent_doze = false;
    static const char usestr[] = "[-abdhi]";

    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "abdhi")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'a':
            after_fork = true;
            break;
        case 'b':
            before_fork = true;
            break;
        case 'd':
            parent_doze = true;
            break;
        case 'h':
            sig_handle = true;
            break;
        case 'i':
            sig_ignore = true;
            break;
        default:
            err_usage(usestr);
        }
    }

    if (optind != argc)
        err_usage(usestr);

    /* Both these happen naturally - but should be explicit when printing configuration */
    if (sig_handle && sig_ignore)
        sig_ignore = false;
    if (before_fork && after_fork)
        after_fork = false;

    printf("Configuration:\n");
    print_bool("Close read fd before fork", before_fork);
    print_bool("Close read fd after  fork", after_fork);
    print_bool("SIGPIPE handled", sig_handle);
    print_bool("SIGPIPE ignored", sig_ignore); 
    print_bool("Parent doze", parent_doze);

    err_setlogopts(ERR_PID);

    errMsgPipeLen = strlen(errMsgPipe);
    char bufin[BUFSIZE] = "empty";
    char bufout[] = "hello soner";
    int bytesin;
    pid_t childpid;
    int fd[2];

    struct sigaction sa;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigfillset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;
    if (sig_ignore)
        sa.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
    if (sig_handle)
        sa.sa_handler = handler;
    if (sigaction(SIGPIPE, &sa, 0) != 0)
        err_syserr("sigaction(SIGPIPE) failed: ");

    printf("Parent: %d\n", (int)getpid());

    if (pipe(fd) == -1)
        err_syserr("pipe failed: ");

    if (before_fork)
        close(fd[0]);

    int val = -999;
    bytesin = strlen(bufin);
    childpid = fork();
    if (childpid == -1)
        err_syserr("fork failed: ");

    if (after_fork)
        close(fd[0]);

    if (childpid)
    {
        if (parent_doze)
            sleep(1);
        val = write(fd[1], bufout, strlen(bufout) + 1);
        if (val < 0)
            err_syserr("write to pipe failed: ");
        err_remark("Parent wrote %d bytes to pipe\n", val);
    }
    else
    {
        bytesin = read(fd[0], bufin, BUFSIZE);
        if (bytesin < 0)
            err_syserr("read from pipe failed: ");
        err_remark("Child read %d bytes from pipe\n", bytesin);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "[%ld]:my bufin is {%.*s}, my bufout is {%s}\n",
            (long)getpid(), bytesin, bufin, bufout);

    return 0;
}
```

It can be difficult (non-obvious, at any rate) to track what happens to the parent process.  Bash generates an exit status of 128 + signal number when a child dies from a signal.  On this machine, SIGPIPE is 13, so an exit status of 141 indicates death from SIGPIPE.

Example runs:

```
$ pipe71; echo $?
Configuration:
  false: Close read fd before fork
  false: Close read fd after  fork
  false: SIGPIPE handled
  false: SIGPIPE ignored
  false: Parent doze
Parent: 97984
pipe71: pid=97984: Parent wrote 12 bytes to pipe
[97984]:my bufin is {empty}, my bufout is {hello soner}
pipe71: pid=97985: Child read 12 bytes from pipe
[97985]:my bufin is {hello soner}, my bufout is {hello soner}
0
$ pipe71 -b; echo $?
Configuration:
   true: Close read fd before fork
  false: Close read fd after  fork
  false: SIGPIPE handled
  false: SIGPIPE ignored
  false: Parent doze
Parent: 97987
pipe71: pid=97988: read from pipe failed: error (9) Bad file descriptor
141
$ pipe71 -a; echo $?
Configuration:
  false: Close read fd before fork
   true: Close read fd after  fork
  false: SIGPIPE handled
  false: SIGPIPE ignored
  false: Parent doze
Parent: 98000
pipe71: pid=98000: Parent wrote 12 bytes to pipe
[98000]:my bufin is {empty}, my bufout is {hello soner}
0
pipe71: pid=98001: read from pipe failed: error (9) Bad file descriptor
$ pipe71 -a -d; echo $?
Configuration:
  false: Close read fd before fork
   true: Close read fd after  fork
  false: SIGPIPE handled
  false: SIGPIPE ignored
   true: Parent doze
Parent: 98004
pipe71: pid=98005: read from pipe failed: error (9) Bad file descriptor
141
$ pipe71 -h -a -d; echo $?
Configuration:
  false: Close read fd before fork
   true: Close read fd after  fork
   true: SIGPIPE handled
  false: SIGPIPE ignored
   true: Parent doze
Parent: 98007
pipe71: pid=98008: read from pipe failed: error (9) Bad file descriptor
signal handled SIGPIPE
pipe71: pid=98007: write to pipe failed: error (32) Broken pipe
1
$ pipe71 -h -a; echo $?
Configuration:
  false: Close read fd before fork
   true: Close read fd after  fork
   true: SIGPIPE handled
  false: SIGPIPE ignored
  false: Parent doze
Parent: 98009
pipe71: pid=98009: Parent wrote 12 bytes to pipe
[98009]:my bufin is {empty}, my bufout is {hello soner}
pipe71: pid=98010: read from pipe failed: error (9) Bad file descriptor
0
$ pipe71 -i -a; echo $?
Configuration:
  false: Close read fd before fork
   true: Close read fd after  fork
  false: SIGPIPE handled
   true: SIGPIPE ignored
  false: Parent doze
Parent: 98013
pipe71: pid=98013: Parent wrote 12 bytes to pipe
[98013]:my bufin is {empty}, my bufout is {hello soner}
0
pipe71: pid=98014: read from pipe failed: error (9) Bad file descriptor
$ pipe71 -d -i -a; echo $?
Configuration:
  false: Close read fd before fork
   true: Close read fd after  fork
  false: SIGPIPE handled
   true: SIGPIPE ignored
   true: Parent doze
Parent: 98015
pipe71: pid=98016: read from pipe failed: error (9) Bad file descriptor
pipe71: pid=98015: write to pipe failed: error (32) Broken pipe
1
$ pipe71 -i -a; echo $?
Configuration:
  false: Close read fd before fork
   true: Close read fd after  fork
  false: SIGPIPE handled
   true: SIGPIPE ignored
  false: Parent doze
Parent: 98020
pipe71: pid=98020: Parent wrote 12 bytes to pipe
[98020]:my bufin is {empty}, my bufout is {hello soner}
0
pipe71: pid=98021: read from pipe failed: error (9) Bad file descriptor
$
```

On my machine (a MacBook Pro running macOS High Sierra 10.13.5, with GCC 8.1.0), if I do not delay the parent, the parent consistently writes to the pipe before the child gets around to closing the file descriptor.  That is not, however, guaranteed behaviour.  It would be possible to add another option (e.g. `-n` for `child_nap`) to make the child nap for a second.

#### Code is available on GitHub

The code for the programs shown above (`fork29.c`, `fork13.c`, `pipe71.c`) are available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `fork13.c`, `fork29.c`, `pipe71.c` in the [src/so-5100-4470](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/so-5100-4470) sub-directory.

Comment: I've had a look at it, and I'm trying to work out what you're proving with it.  If you close the read end of the pipe before the fork, the write will always fail.  If you only close the read end of the pipe after the fork, there are scheduling issues to deal with, and it may be that the parent can write to the pipe before the child closes the read end, in which case the write will succeed but the read will ultimately fail.  I've not understood why you are not printing the values returned by `write()` and `read()` — as opposed to strings that might be involved what's in the buffers.

Comment: I wanted to recognize reason of need for closing, as I highlighted in the picture, https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx3O4.png. The bottom colored one is described by your example program. The yellow one is with mine. _I've not understood why you are not printing the values returned by `write()` and `read()`_ I just intended to catch the mentioned error(s). That's why I glossed over them. Did I think wrong or omit important thing??

Comment: See the 'Adaptation of the code from answer by OP' section for a reconstruction of your code into something that can demonstrate what you're looking for — I think.  I prefer to set options on the command line rather than by rerunning the compiler.  It's easier in the long-run.

Comment: Something I realized that - related to my mislooking - at closing read end of the pipe we got `SIGPIPE(0x000D)` after we close reader. As far as I know, **If the writer process writes faster than the reader process consumes the data, and if the pipe cannot store more data, the writer process blocks until more capacity becomes available.** and **Writing to a pipe that doesn't have a reading process is treated as an error condition; it generates a `SIGPIPE` signal**. But seemingly our `SIGPIPE` termination is not related to the mentioned thing. Because if I change 65536 to 20, I got 0x0000. Why?

Comment: I don't understand reason of being gotten `SIGPIPE(0x000D)` there. Would you mind telling me?

Comment: Your statements in bold are accurate, but the pipe buffer capacity is often 64 KiB on modern machines (back in the old days, it was often 5 KiB).  When you change `65536` to `20`, the `seq` process doesn't fill the pipe, and probably gets to write all its 20 lines of output at once (successfully) before the `sed` process gets a chance to read anything and exit.  So, `seq` is successful then.  The main times you run into problems with (not) closing the read end of the pipe is when the pipe buffer fills and the only process left that could read from it is the one that is trying to write to it.

Comment: Try an intermediate value like 1536 or 2048; there's a decent chance that with one of those, you'll still get SIGPIPE even though the buffer is not full (6573 or 9133 bytes; if your standard I/O buffer size is 16 KiB, you might need to go to 4096, for 19373 bytes output; 1024 only generates 4013 bytes).  Not guaranteed; it depends on the scheduling of different processes.

Comment: I'm reading it for about 40 minutes but I can't understand the saying. Could you clarify a bit more _the only process left that could read from it is the one that is trying to write to it_ ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to help.  Maybe: `int main(void) { int fd[2]; pipe(fd); while (write(fd[1], "abcd", sizeof("abcd")-1) > 0) ; close(fd[0]); close(fd[1]); return 0; }` — that will write to the pipe until the pipe is full.  It will never get SIGPIPE from the `write()` because there is a process with the read end of the pipe open, but that process is busy writing, so the pipe will never be emptied at all, so it will be blocked on a write very quickly (but won't consume any CPU cycles).  No forking to confuse anything in that example.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is related to place of `close(fd[0]);` I comment out its reason in the code. Now, I get the error expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define BUFSIZE 100

char const * errMsgPipe = "signal handled SIGPIPE\n";
int errMsgPipeLen;

void handler(int x) {
    write(2, errMsgPipe, errMsgPipeLen);
}

int main(void) {
    errMsgPipeLen = strlen(errMsgPipe);
    char bufin[BUFSIZE] = "empty";
    char bufout[] = "hello soner";
    int bytesin;
    pid_t childpid;
    int fd[2];

    struct sigaction sa;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigfillset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_handler = handler;
    sigaction(SIGPIPE, &sa, 0);

    if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
        perror("Failed to create the pipe");
        return 1;
    }

    close(fd[0]); // <-- it's in order for no process has an open read descriptor


    int val = -999;
    bytesin = strlen(bufin);
    childpid = fork();
    if (childpid == -1) {
        perror("Failed to fork");
        return 1;
    }


/*
 * close(fd[0]); <---- if it were here, we wouldn't get expected error and signal
 *                      since, parent can be reached to write(fd[1], .... ) call
 *                      before the child close(fd[0]); call defined here it. 
 *          It means there is by child open read descriptor seen by parent.
 */

// sleep(1);     <---- we can prove my saying by calling sleep() here



    if (childpid) {

       val = write(fd[1], bufout, strlen(bufout)+1);
       if (val < 0) {
           perror("writing process error");
       }

    }
    else {
        bytesin = read(fd[0], bufin, BUFSIZE);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "[%ld]:my bufin is {%.*s}, my bufout is {%s}\n",
            (long)getpid(), bytesin, bufin, bufout);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
signal handled SIGPIPE
writing process error: Broken pipe
[27289]:my bufin is {empty}, my bufout is {hello soner}
[27290]:my bufin is {empty}, my bufout is {hello soner}
```

Therewithal, the saying that *if the parent's write operation fails, the child's `bufin` contains `empty`* is verified.