# Why write to closed pipe returns success

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I recently read a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004470/closing-unused-pipe-file-descriptors). In this post,[Soner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4990642/soner-from-the-ottoman-empire)closed the read end of the pipe for both parent and child process.But when write to the pipe, It seems that no SIGPIPE signal is generated.

I modified the code,to make sure that read end of the pipe is really closed and **write** call return without any error.

here is my code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <signal.h>
#define BUFSIZE 100

char const * errMsgPipe = "signal handled SIGPIPE\n";
int errMsgPipeLen;

void handler(int x) {
    write(2, errMsgPipe, errMsgPipeLen);
}

int main(void) {
    errMsgPipeLen = strlen(errMsgPipe);
    char bufin[BUFSIZE] = "empty";
    char bufout[] = "hello soner";
    int bytesin;
    pid_t childpid;
    int fd[2];

    struct sigaction sa;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigfillset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_handler = handler;
    sigaction(SIGPIPE, &sa, 0);

    if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
        perror("Failed to create the pipe");
        return 1;
    }
    bytesin = strlen(bufin);
    childpid = fork();
    if (childpid == -1) {
        perror("Failed to fork");
        return 1;
    }

    close(fd[0]);

    if (childpid) {
        int ret = write(fd[1], bufout, strlen(bufout)+1);
        if (ret < 0) {
            perror("write");
        } else {
                printf("write success, ret: %d\n", ret );
        }
        wait(NULL);
    }
    else{
        bytesin = read(fd[0], bufin, BUFSIZE);
        if(bytesin == -1) {
                perror("child: read");
        }
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "[%ld]:my bufin is {%.*s}, my bufout is {%s}\n",
            (long)getpid(), bytesin, bufin, bufout);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
write success, ret: 12
child: read: Bad file descriptor
[9168]:my bufin is {empty}, my bufout is {hello soner}
[9167]:my bufin is {empty}, my bufout is {hello soner}
```

I modified the code as bellow:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define BUFSIZE 100

char const * errMsgPipe = "signal handled SIGPIPE\n";
int errMsgPipeLen;

void handler(int x) {
    write(2, errMsgPipe, errMsgPipeLen);
}

int main(void) {
    errMsgPipeLen = strlen(errMsgPipe);
    char bufin[BUFSIZE] = "empty";
    char bufout[] = "hello soner";
    int bytesin;
    pid_t childpid;
    int fd[2];

    struct sigaction sa;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigfillset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_handler = handler;
    sigaction(SIGPIPE, &sa, 0);

    if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
        perror("Failed to create the pipe");
        return 1;
    }
    close(fd[0]);
    bytesin = strlen(bufin);
    childpid = fork();
    if (childpid == -1) {
        perror("Failed to fork");
        return 1;
    }


    if (childpid) {
        int flag = fcntl(fd[0], F_GETFD);
        if(flag = -1) {
                printf("pid:[%d], fcntl: %s\n", getpid(), strerror(errno));
        } else {
                printf("pip: [%d], fd[0] is not closed\n");
        }
        if (write(fd[1], bufout, strlen(bufout)+1) < 0) {
            perror("write");
        }
        //
    }
    else{
        int flag = fcntl(fd[0], F_GETFD);
        if(flag = -1) {
                printf("pid:[%d], fcntl: %s\n", getpid(), strerror(errno));
        } else {
                printf("pip: [%d], fd[0] is not closed\n");
        }
        bytesin = read(fd[0], bufin, BUFSIZE);
        if(bytesin == -1) {
                perror("read");
        }
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "[%ld]:my bufin is {%.*s}, my bufout is {%s}\n",
            (long)getpid(), bytesin, bufin, bufout);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I run the program multiple times, it produces different result.
For example:

```
pid:[9200], fcntl: Bad file descriptor
signal handled SIGPIPE
write: Broken pipe
pid:[9201], fcntl: Bad file descriptor
[9200]:my bufin is {empty}, my bufout is {hello soner}
read: Bad file descriptor
[9201]:my bufin is {empty}, my bufout is {hello soner}
```

another result:

```
pid:[9189], fcntl: Bad file descriptor
[9189]:my bufin is {empty}, my bufout is {hello soner}
pid:[9190], fcntl: Bad file descriptor
read: Bad file descriptor
[9190]:my bufin is {empty}, my bufout is {hello soner}
```

Comment: Your parent read is never going to work.  `close(fd[0]);` is always run in both the child and parent processes, yet it comes before `bytesin = read(fd[0],...);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    close(fd[0]);

    if (childpid > 0) { /* parent code */
        int ret = write(fd[1], bufout, strlen(bufout)+1);
```

As the `close(fd[0]);` in the parent does happen to make a `write(2)` call immediately, there's a chance that the child has not yet started to run  (and indeed this is the most probable thing to happen as the parent is ready to run once the kernel has knowledge of the child pid, while it still has housekeeping to do in the child), and so, the child has not had time to do the `close(fd[0]);` itself, when the write in the parent is done.  Indeed, it is very frequent that the parent continues the execution while the child has not yet even been scheduled, and this will be probably most frequent thing.

If you put a `sleep(1)`, after the `close(fd[0]);` statement above, (in both, parent and child processes) you will observe your desired ouptut, as by then, both, parent and child have started and both have had a chance to do the `close()` call, well before the `write()` syscall takes place in the parent process.

The sequence of events (w.o. the sleep()) is:

1. parent starts and creates the pipe.
2. parent forks.
3. parent closes reading end.
4. parent writes.
5. child gets scheduled
6. child closes reading end.
   (and parent got its write ok)

With the sleep, the sequence becomes:

1. parent starts and creates the pipe.
2. parent forks.
3. parent closes reading end.
4. parent sleeps.
5. child gets scheduled.
6. child closes reading end.
7. child sleeps.
8. parent awakens from sleep.
9. parent writes and gets error. (and signal handler is executed before returning from write call, already in user mode)

It is worth considering that the first process to reach:

- the `write(2)` system call in the parent.
- the `close(2)` system call in the child.

will lock the inode, and will make the other process to wait to finish the system call.  This will make the writing process to write the full message, even if the message has not been completely written before the close is started in the child or nothing at all, if the close in the child started first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I didn't know that the inode will be locked.   Can you recommend me some references on this？

Comment: _The design of the UNIX  operating system_ by Maurice J. Bach.  It's an old book that describes all the UNIX system calls (as of Sys III release)  Also _The Lion's Comentary on Unix 6th Edition_ by John Lions.  This last uses the source code of the 6th ed. kernel as reference.

Answer (score 3):

If the write returned success, then the child didn't get to execute the `close` yet. You claim the child closed the read end of the pipe, but there's nothing to indicate that it has done so (yet).

It's a race condition. Does the parent call `write` first, or does the child call `close` first? In the first case, the write is successful. In the latter case, it's not. Both scenarios are possible since there's no synchronization that would ensure otherwise.